# Why can't I listen to the radio in Winamp but can in Windows Media Player?

Tags: winamp, internet-radio

The url of the radio is:

> http://200.43.193.190/vale.

This is the site of the radio:

> http://www.10musica.com/contenidos/popup_radio.html?radio=43

Comment: Do you have a firewall blocking WinAmp?

Comment: I guess asf/wmv plugin is missing or not registered.

Answer (score 1):

As é_ho suggests, ensure your Winamp isn't blocked by a firewall.

My winamp gives "error syncing to MPEG" when I try to open the URL.  Using curl, it looks like the radio URL is pushing an ASF stream:

```
$ curl http://200.43.193.190/vale
[Reference]
Ref1=http://200.43.193.190/vale?MSWMExt=.asf
Ref2=http://10.0.8.33:80/vale?MSWMExt=.asf
```

ASF is a [Microsoft proprietary stream format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Systems_Format), so my Winamp may not know what to do with it.  The current version of Winamp [claims support](http://www.winamp.com/player/features) for ASF files, so you might try updating, or look for a plugin for your version.